# How to serve a Cramp::Websocket and a normal Rack app on the same port?

Tags: ruby, websocket, rack, thin, cramp

I'm trying to use the same port to serve normal HTTP traffic as well as an HTML5 websocket via [Cramp](http://cramp.in/documentation#websockets) (which is built on top of EventMachine), using Ruby 1.9.3 and [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) 1.3.1. Here is a minimal, self-contained example:

```
require 'thin'
require 'cramp'
require 'http_router'

Cramp::Websocket.backend = :thin

class SocketApp < Cramp::Action
  self.transport = :websocket

  on_start = :connected
  on_finish = :disconnected
  on_data = :message

  def connected
    puts 'Client connected'
  end
  def disconnected
    puts 'Client disconnected'
  end
  def message(msg)
    puts "Got message: #{msg}"
    render 'Here is your reply'
  end
end

class WebApp
  def call(env)
    [ 200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, <<EOF
<html><head>
<script>
  function init() {
    function log(msg) { document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += msg + '<br>'; }
    var socketUri = 'ws://' + document.location.host + '/socket';
    log('Socket URI: ' + socketUri);
    var socket = new WebSocket(socketUri);
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
      log('onopen');
      socket.send('Is there anybody out there?');
      log('sent message');
    };
    socket.onclose = function(e) {
      log('onclose; code = ' + e.code + ', reason = ' + e.reason);
    };
    socket.onerror = function(e) {
      log('onerror');
    };
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      log('onmessage; data = ' + e.data);
    };
  }
</script>
</head><body onload='init();'>
  <h1>Serving Cramp::Websocket and normal Rack app on the same port</h1>
  <p id='log'></p>
</body></html>
EOF
    ]
  end
end

app = HttpRouter.new do
  add('/socket').to SocketApp
  add('/').to WebApp.new
end

run app
```

If you want to try this for yourself, stick this code into a file named `config.ru` and run `thin start`. You need the gems `thin`, `cramp` and `http_router` to be installed.

The idea is that the JavaScript code makes a WebSocket connection to `ws://localhost:3000/socket`, which echoes messages sent to it, but this does not work as intended. The `open` event fires, there is no error upon sending the message, but we never get a response.

From the server's point of view, no connection has been made, as the `Client connected` message does not get printed.

Using `thin start -D`, I can see the HTTP 101 happening, and some binary data is being exchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: If I split the file in two parts, rip out the `HttpRouter`, and run two `thin` instances on different ports, it still doesn't work. So the problem is in the socket code, not in the `HttpRouter` or the `WebApp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is cheating, but I finally solved it by switching to a different library: [websocket-rack](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-rack). For the curious, the corrected code follows:

```
require 'thin'
require 'http_router'
require 'rack/websocket'

class SocketApp < Rack::WebSocket::Application
  def on_open(env)
    puts 'Client connected'
  end
  def on_close(env)
    puts 'Client disconnected'
  end
  def on_message(env, message)
    puts "Got message: #{message}"
    send_data 'Here is your reply'
  end
end

class WebApp
  def call(env)
    [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, <<EOF
<html><head>
<script>
  function init() {
    function log(msg) { document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += msg + '<br>'; }
    var socketUri = 'ws://' + document.location.host + '/socket';
    log('Socket URI: ' + socketUri);
    var socket = new WebSocket(socketUri);
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
      log('onopen');
      socket.send('Is there anybody out there?');
      log('sent message');
    };
    socket.onclose = function(e) {
      log('onclose; code = ' + e.code + ', reason = ' + e.reason);
    };
    socket.onerror = function(e) {
      log('onerror');
    };
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      log('onmessage; data = ' + e.data);
    };
  }
</script>
</head><body onload='init();'>
  <h1>Serving WebSocket and normal Rack app on the same port</h1>
  <p id='log'></p>
</body></html>
EOF
    ]
  end
end

app = HttpRouter.new do
  add('/socket').to(SocketApp.new)
  add('/').to(WebApp.new)
end

run app
```